# How to export matplotlib plots as iframes

Tags: matplotlib, iframe, google-sites

I want to generate some plots with Matplotlib and then generate iframes to embed in a Google Sites site.

I would like that if the image change, the change be reflected on my Google Site.

I have tried:

```
from matplotlib.pyplot import figure
import mpld3

fig = figure()
ax = fig.gca()
ax.plot([1,5,3,4])


hola= mpld3.save_html(fig,'myfig.html',template_type='simple')
```

If I open myfig.html on the browser and go to View Page Source, I can see

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://mpld3.github.io/js/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://mpld3.github.io/js/mpld3.v0.3.js"></script>

<style>

</style>

<div id="fig_el190911208844747686822225975"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">

  !function(mpld3){

       mpld3.draw_figure("fig_el190911208844747686822225975", {"width": 432.0, "height": 288.0, "axes": [{"bbox": [0.125, 0.125, 0.775, 0.755], "xlim": [-0.15000000000000002, 3.15], "ylim": [0.8, 5.2], "xdomain": [-0.15000000000000002, 3.15], "ydomain": [0.8, 5.2], "xscale": "linear", "yscale": "linear", "axes": [{"position": "bottom", "nticks": 9, "tickvalues": null, "tickformat": null, "scale": "linear", "fontsize": 10.0, "grid": {"gridOn": false}, "visible": true}, {"position": "left", "nticks": 11, "tickvalues": null, "tickformat": null, "scale": "linear", "fontsize": 10.0, "grid": {"gridOn": false}, "visible": true}], "axesbg": "#FFFFFF", "axesbgalpha": null, "zoomable": true, "id": "el19091120884476504", "lines": [{"data": "data01", "xindex": 0, "yindex": 1, "coordinates": "data", "id": "el19091120885398384", "color": "#1F77B4", "linewidth": 1.5, "dasharray": "none", "alpha": 1, "zorder": 2, "drawstyle": "default"}], "paths": [], "markers": [], "texts": [], "collections": [], "images": [], "sharex": [], "sharey": []}], "data": {"data01": [[0.0, 1.0], [1.0, 5.0], [2.0, 3.0], [3.0, 4.0]]}, "id": "el19091120884474768", "plugins": [{"type": "reset"}, {"type": "zoom", "button": true, "enabled": false}, {"type": "boxzoom", "button": true, "enabled": false}]});
  }(mpld3);
```

So If I copy this code in my Google Sites I can see the picture.

But I need that if I save a new picture in `myfig.html` that I can see those changes in the site.